# How to check if a element is repeated in a IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

This is a code example from solution. I'm looking for the way to eliminate Problem classes repeated. I was watching Contains method in List.

```
public IEnumerable<Problem> Create(int quantify)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < quantify; i++)
    {
        yield return Create();
    }
}
```

Comment: what does the code sample have to the do with the question? With an enumerator block like that you can get no `ReferenceEquals : true` instances, and likely only `IEquatable<Problem>::Equals : true` elements... (depending on definitions of both `Problem` and `Create()`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you simply want to eliminate any duplicates and `Problem` supports equality then use the `Distinct` method.

```
IEnumerable<Problem> collection = ...;
IEnumerable<Problem> noRepeats = collection.Distinct();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick to an iterator block you could use an `HashSet` to not yield any repeated `Problem` instances in the first place:

```
public IEnumerable<Problem> Create(int quantify)
{
    HashSet<Problem> problems = new HashSet<Problem>();
    for (int i = 0; i < quantify; i++)
    {
        var problem = Create();
        if(!problems.Contains(problem))
        {
           yield return problem;
           problems.Add(problem);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If a distinction is based on the property you can use [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx)

```
Create(q).GroupBy(p => p.PropertyToCompare).Select(p => p.First());
```